# How do I get a background image on top of an img?

Tags: html, css, image

I need to put an icon on top of an image of the product. I have been working on this for quite a while. What am I missing?

.special-corner is a div with the icon as the background image, which needs to display on top of the img.

```
<div class="vertical-vehicle-spotlight-item">
  <div class="vertical-item-photo">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="special-corner">
        <img width="260" height="146" src="kjhasd.png">

.vertical-vehicle-spotlight-item {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer !important;
    height: 253px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 260px;
}

.vertical-item-photo {
    height: 146px;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 260px;
}

.special-corner {
    background-image: url("/img/special-corner.png");
    background-position: 100% -1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
}

.vertical-item-photo img {
    height: 146px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 260px;
}
```

Edit: Here's the fiddle, thanks for the idea from @Mooseman. http://jsfiddle.net/heetertc/nTMun/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heetertc/nTMun/ thanks for the idea @Mooseman

Answer (score 2):

Use `z-index: 1` on the image and `z-index: 2` on `.special-corner`.

Comment: Check out the Fiddle, this does not work for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/heetertc/nTMun/

Comment: Since the image was a child of `.special-corner` and you were using a background image for your icon, the background image was underneath. I  edited your HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/nTMun/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a position property other than static (the initial value) for z-index to work. You can give `.special-corner` position: relative and then give it a positive z-index for it to overlay the image.

Comment: I added "position: relative; z-index: 2" to .special-corner, that didn't work so I also added "position: relative (also tried absolute);  z-index: 1" to the img, still didn't work. When I delete the image I can see the icon, so I'm not sure why this method isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` to enforce elements "depth". Like lower on image and higher on your `.special-corner`